# GDB no debugging symbols found

Tags: c++, debugging, makefile, gdb, g++

I am trying to compile a program consisting of two source files:
wildcardtrie.h, wildcardtrie.cpp 
using a Makefile. However, when I run GDB to debug, I get the following error:

```
Reading symbols from /home/meric/Documents/Random/SectionLeading/wildcardtrie...(no    debugging symbols found)...done.
```

I have tried a number of different compiler flags, none of which worked. The thing that perplexes me is that I have used a nearly identical Makefile in other programs and missing symbols has never been a problem. I have included the Makefile below:

```
CC=g++  
CFLAGS = -g -ggdb g++ -O0 -Wall -Wfloat-equal -Wtype-limits -Wpointer-arith -Wlogical- op -fno-diagnostics-show-option 

LDFLAGS = -g -ggdb -std=c++0x 


programs = wildcardtrie


all : $(programs)

clean:
     rm -f $(programs) core *.o

.PHONY: clean all
```

I have tried removing '-g' and '-ggdb' in the compiler and linker flags, but nothing seems to work. When I call 'make', I get the following output on the terminal:

```
g++    -c -o wildcardtrie.o wildcardtrie.cpp
g++  -g -ggdb -std=c++0x   wildcardtrie.o   -o wildcardtrie
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When building C++ programs, `make` uses the `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` variables.

Comment: Also, having both `-g` and `-ggdb` is redundant.

Comment: Hi, I recognize that -g and -ggdb is redundant but I was just trying anything. Also, when I changed CC to CXX I got a bunch of 'undefined reference' linker errors.

Comment: You need to change the linker to `g++` as well: `LD = g++`.

Comment: I did that and got the following error: 'g++: error: g++: No such file or directory'

Comment: Can you please edit your question so it contains the complete build output, after cleaning?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean by 'build output'?

Comment: When you run `make` in a console, you get a lot of output. Please include that output in the question, after running `make clean`.

Comment: Ah, I see you added it. As you can see there are only the default flags when compiling the `wildcardtrie.cpp` file, which leads me to guess you didn't set `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: So after running 'make clean' and then running 'make', it turns out that gdb was able to read symbols! That worked. Thanks for being patient and helping out! What exactly does 'make clean' do?

Comment: I think you really need to read more about `make`. The `clean` in `make clean` invokes the `clean` target in the makefile.

Answer (score 1):

> `g++    -c -o wildcardtrie.o wildcardtrie.cpp`

This clearly shows that `-g` is *not* on your compile line (which is exactly the cause of your problem).

To get `-g` there, either add it to `CXXFLAGS` (this is the preferred solution), or just write the compile rule explicitly (instead of relying on built-in make rule):

```
wildcardtrie.o: wildcardtrie.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o wildcardtrie.o wildcardtrie.cpp
```